# SP 2010: Disable checkbox field on condition in a library

Tags: 2010, document-library, list-form, edit-form

I'd like to disable a yes/no checkbox field if the other checkbox field in the document library is checked and vice-versa. I've written the below code and have added it in a CEWP for the edit form but I'm unsuccessful so far.

[image: Code]

Answer (score 1):

I do it a little differently in my scripts, where we grab the value, hide the checkbox all together, and then just show the value. I find it a clean UI for users than a grayed out box which people always like to click on. Check out https://lozzisp2013.codeplex.com/

```
//theCell is the TD tag containing the checkbox
theControls = theCell.find("input,select,textarea,img"); //grab any control, works with checboxes and other field types (but not all, see link above for other types)
value = "<span class='readonly'>" + theControls.val() + "<span>";
theControls.hide();
theCell.prepend(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

> $( "input[title='Publish']" ).attr('disabled',true);

You have to Use

> $( "input[id^='Publish']" ).attr('disabled',true);

Comment: $( "input[title='Publish']" ).attr('disabled',true);

Above code works fine in developer tools.

Comment: Use This $( "input[id^='Publish']" ).attr('disabled',true); It will Work What exactly you want ?

Comment: Not sure what 'id^' is. Publish is the name of the column.

Comment: id^ it means your html element id ends with 'publish' string

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
$("input[title *='Publish']").change(function() {   
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    if(checked){
        $("input[title='Publish']").attr("readonly","true");
    }
    else{ $("input[title='Publish']").attr("readonly","false");
    }   
});
```

Comment: It didn't work for me